# How do I add an underline to unvisited links only?

Tags: css, hyperlink

I want the links in my page to have different `text-decoration`'s (or similar effect).

For "fresh" or "unvisited" links, I want `text-decoration: underline` for `a:link`, but `text-decoration: none` for `a:visited` links.

For some reason, CSS seems to demand that `a:visited`inherit `text-decoration` and similar properties from `a:link`. How do I get around this? I tried using `border-bottom`, to no avail.

Comment: @Andrew How would that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under Mozilla (as [documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Privacy_and_the_%3avisited_selector)) and Chromium (possibly the same for Chrome), empirically verified:

> You will still be able to visually style visited links, but there are now limits on what styles you can use. Only the following properties can be applied to visited links:

- `color`
- `background-color`
- `border-color` (and its sub-properties)
- `outline-color`
- The `color` parts of the fill and stroke properties

> In addition, even for the properties you can set for visited links, you won't be able to change the transparency between unvisited and visited links, as you otherwise would be able to using rgba() or hsla() color values or the transparent keyword.

This is to avoid JavaScript on malicious pages being able to access your browser history through examining the rendered styles of lists of links (in hidden elements).

I'm unable to test Internet Explorer, but the above also *seems* true for Opera.

So, effectively, for the majority of properties the `:visited` links cannot be styled differently to the un-visited links; and in those cases where they *can*, the browser will, effectively, lie about it and 'pretend' the link is unvisited.

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate the text-decoration difference by using border-bottom and specifying the color of your background for the border on visited links:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
a:visited {
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

This trick will only work if you have a solid color background to use. Here's a jsfiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/gDSxS/

Answer (score 1):

Well it's not ideal but I found you can use underline and change the border color on the visited. (tested in firefox)

Demo here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sbhFA